# Test that a Blazor EventCallback is called

Tags: c#, blazor, bunit

If I have a Blazor component:

```
@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnEvent { get; set; }
}
```

And a bUnit test:

```
@code {
    var cut = RenderComponent<MyComp>(builder =>
    { 
        builder.Add(mc => mc.OnEvent, Handler("Fired"));
    }

    await cut.Instance.OnEvent.InvokeAsync();

    private void Handler(string val) {}
}
```

Two questions:

1. Can I convert this to use an arbitrary method defined and setup using Moq?

I have tried:

```cs
Mock<EventHandler<string>> mockHandler = new Mock<EventHandler<string>>();
mockHandler.Setup(m => m.X(It.IsAny<object>(), "Fired"));
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the mockHandler method to the component.

2. How can I verify that OnEvent is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont call EventCallbacks directly in your tests, trigger them as you would through a user interaction.

E.g. to test the EventCallback in the following component:

```
<button @onclick="Clicked">Click Me</button> 
@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback Clicked { get; set; }
}
```

Do this:

```cs
  [Fact]
  public void TestClickTriggered() 
  {
    var called = false;
    var cut = RenderComponent<MyComp>(builder =>
    { 
        // Pass an inline lambda that updates `called` variable
        builder.Add(mc => mc.Clicked, val => called = true);
    }

    // Find the button and trigger the onclick eventhandler, 
    // simulating a user clicking a button in the browser.
    cut.Find("button").Click();

    Assert.True(called);
  }
```

Learn more over on https://bunit.dev/docs/getting-started